# How can I convert Lua HMAC SHA256 digest to a hexadecimal string (creates Facebook appsecret_proof token)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, lua, hex, sha, sha256

I've been spending time reading about the HTTPLuaModule for Nginx and find that there are some great ways developers have been able to [SHA256 sign Amazon Web Services](http://bl.ocks.org/justincormack/948423) using a key and string. As a junior developer who is a Lua noob, I would like to use the HTTPLuaModule to generate Facebook appsecret_proof tokens. Currently I found that there is the [LuaCrypto module](http://luacrypto.luaforge.net/manual.html#reference) for Lua to generate HMAC via SHA256 but it doesn't exactly match the implementation needed for Facebook's token:

`digest = crypto.hmac.digest('sha256', user-access-token, app-secret, true) ## what next to convert digest into hexadecimal string?`

Unlike in the Amazon example above, the token doesn't need to be Base64 encode but instead the HMAC needs to be turned into a string of double length using only hexadecimal digits (hence hexidecimal!).

In Python I can obtain the token with:

`import hashlib
import hmac
token = hmac.new(app-secret, user-access-token, hashlib.sha256).hexadecimal()`

Thoughts? Any better modules that have methods to convert digest's into hexadecimal strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
local secretProof = digest:final()
```

source: http://mkottman.github.io/luacrypto/manual.html#reference

Comment: I cannot believe how much of an oversight I made - all I had to do was switch the [raw] flag to false -- ```digest = crypto.hmac.digest('sha256', user-access-token, app-secret, false)``` as clearly outlined in the [documentation](http://mkottman.github.io/luacrypto/manual.html#reference). Thanks for pointing me to the above method though -- I'll be needing this elsewhere :-)